# What is an NBA Rodeo Road Trip?

Tags: basketball, terminology, nba

Recently I have heard sports broadcasters referring to the San Antonio Spurs as being on a "Nine Game Rodeo Road Trip", but I'm not sure what that term means or where it came from. The Spurs are on a nine game road trip where they have so far won all of their games.

Does "Rodeo Road Trip" simply mean that they have won every game on their road trip?

Comment: The Chicago Bulls and Chicago Blackhawks go on a Circus trip every fall in mid-November because a circus is occupying the United Center for those two weeks.

Comment: The Lakers and Clippers have weeklong road trip every February because of the Grammys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AT&T Center hosts the San Antonio Stock Show & Rodeo.  While this event is happening the Spurs are forced to take an extended series of away games. This is informally known as the "[Rodeo Road Trip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Antonio_Spurs#The_Spurs_in_San_Antonio)."